# How to make paraview read datafiles automatically?

Tags: paraview

I'm not sure if I ask in a right place. My simulation generates datafiles at each time step on a time line. I want paraview can load the new datafile at current time step automatically whenever the new datafile is generated by the simulation. Does paraview have this function or I need to write a customised script? Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you have to write a customized script. Currently there is a [uservoice suggestion](http://paraview.uservoice.com/forums/11350-general/suggestions/315870-reload-button) that suggests exactly your wish. But it is planned since 2010 and there is still no progress. I don't know what is that difficult. The uservoice suggestion is top voted btw.